# Закраска консоли в цвета фонов C++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, bash

Есть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

static int done = 0;

using namespace std;

namespace con {
    
    int comax() {
        struct winsize w;
        ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
        return(w.ws_col);
    }
    
    int romax() {
        struct winsize w;
        ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
        return(w.ws_row);
    }
    
    ostream& ED(ostream& s) {
        return s << string("\033[2J");
    }
    
    ostream& EL(ostream& s) {
        return s << string("\033[K");
    }
    
    class estream {
        private:
        string escape;
        public:
        estream(string e) : escape(e) {};
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, estream);
    };
    
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, estream e) {
        s << e.escape << flush;
        return s;
    }
    
    estream CUP(int y, int x) {
        ostringstream sout;
        sout << "\033[" << y << ";" << x << "H";
        return estream(sout.str());
    }
    
    estream SGR(int r) {
        ostringstream sout;
        sout << "\033[" << r << "m";
        return estream(sout.str());
    }
    
}

using con::SGR;
using con::CUP;

void interruptor(int signo) {
    done = signo;
    return;
}

int kbin() {
    char buf[512];
    int n=0;
    int flags = fcntl(0, F_GETFL);
    usleep(1);
    fcntl(0, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    n = read(0, buf, 512);
    fcntl(0, F_SETFL, flags /* & ~O_NONBLOCK */);
    return(n);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int m;
    
    cout << SGR(30+7);
    cout << SGR(40+4);
    cout << SGR(1);
    cout << con::CUP(24, 1);
    
    cout << con::ED << "^C or Enter to exit" << flush;
    
    cout << con::CUP(23, 1);
    cout << con::romax() << "x" << con::comax() << flush;
    
    int i;
    int t;
    int y = 0, x = 1;
    char a;
    int f, b;
    srand(getpid());
    signal(SIGINT, interruptor);
    a = 32; b = 40; f = (30 + 7);
    while(done < 1) {
        if ( y < 22 )
        y++;
        else
        {
            y = 1;
            if ( b < 47 )
            b++;
            else
            b = 40;
        }
        t = rand() % 10;
        for(i = 1; i <= 80; i++)
        {
            cout << SGR(b) << CUP(y, i);
            cout << SGR(f) << a << flush;
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(t));
        }
        if(kbin() > 0)
        break;
    }
    cout << CUP(24, 1) << SGR(0) << con::EL;
    system("clear");
    
    return(m);
    
}
```

он закрашивает терминал во все цвета фона в порядке увеличения их escape-кодов.
На данный момент он закрашивает слева-направо и когда докрасит строку переходит на следующую. При закраске последней строки он возвращается на 1-ю и меняет цвет.
Можно ли сделать так чтобы закраска происходила не слева-направо и переходила на следующую строку, а вся строка закрашивалась одновременно, и, после небольшой паузы, переходила на следующую строку?

Comment: Вы бы все ж таки операционную систему хотя бы указали...

Comment: простите, я не подумал об этом

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно. Для этого нужно заменить внутренний цикл на следующий код:

```cpp
for (i = 1; i <= 80; i++) {
    cout << SGR(b) << CUP(y, i);
    cout << SGR(f) << a << flush;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(t));
}
cout << flush; // добавлено
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100)); // добавлено
```

Comment: не работает. я пробовал убирать ***flush*** за цикл, но думаю дело не в этом

Comment: Попробуйте заменить cout на cerr внутри цикла. Некоторые терминалы не обновляют вывод до тех пор, пока не получат новый символ новой строки, который используется при выводе на cerr.
Если это не поможет, попробуйте запустить этот код в другом терминале, возможно, проблема связана с конфигурацией вашего текущего терминала.

Comment: Все же ваш код заработал как нужно, после того как я убрал ***flush*** и паузу внутри цикла. Благодарю.